# how to install xampp or lamp-server

Tags: xampp

when i want to install `xampp server` using this command

```
xampp-linux-x64-5.5.30-0-installer
```

it shows me error:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-*-xampp-linux-x64-5.5.30-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's the error message?

Comment: i found the solution follow this steps
1--> Open terminal and goto file location where is xampp is locted located
2--> In terminal type <<<<  sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.14-0-installer.run    >>>>
3--> sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.14-0-installer.run

that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the command

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.5.30-0-installer.run
```

Only then you can execute it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download `xampp` (https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).
2. open the location where the downloaded file is exists by using terminal, if my downloaded file exists in Downloads directory.
   e.g: `cd /$HOME/Downloads`
3. Give permissions to that file: `chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.9-1-installer.run`
4. Run that file: `sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.9-1-installer.run`